# Problema con API: Sepomex - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

buen día, mi problema es el siguiente:
Mi equipo y yo estamos desarrollando una aplicación con Laravel, pero tenemos un problema, estamos utilizando una API de Sepomex la cuál, al introducir un código postal, busca a qué Estado, Municipio y Colonia pertenece, lo que pasa es que debemos de introducir el código postal en nuestro código para que no nos genere error al actualizar la página, pero debemos de introducirlo desde el navegador y desde ahí, poder buscarlo para que nos arroje sus correspondientes campos.

Nuestro código:

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="colonia">Colonia</label>
    <select name="colonia" class="dropdown-item">
        <option value="">Seleccione una colonia</option>

        <?php
        $codigo_postal = "04369";

        if(@isset($_GET['codigo_postal']))
        { 
            $codigo_postal = $_GET['codigo_postal'];
        }


        $endpoint_sepomex = "http://api-sepomex.hckdrk.mx/query/info_cp/";
        $url = $endpoint_sepomex . $codigo_postal;
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $datos = json_decode($json, true);
        for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++)
        {
            $colonia = $datos[$i]["response"]["asentamiento"];
            $delegacion = $datos[$i]["response"]["municipio"];
            $estado = $datos[$i]["response"]["estado"];
            $ciudad = $datos[$i]["response"]["ciudad"];
            $colonia1 = $colonia;
        }

?>

            @foreach ($datos as $dato)
                <option value="{{ $colonia }}">{{$colonia}}</option>
            @endforeach

    </select>       
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="estado">Estado</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="estado" id="estado" value="{{  $estado }}">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="{{ $ciudad }}">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="delegacion">Alcaldía/Municipio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="delegacion" id="delegacion" value="{{ $delegacion }}">
</div>
```

Lo que queremos es introducirlo desde aquí, para que lo encuentre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado, le recomiendo lo siguiente, capturar el código postal con jquery y enviarlo vía Ajax intente hacer el consumo de la API vía Curl o vía Guzzlehttp y devuelvan el response a la petición Ajax y via Jquery modifiquen los div donde deben colocar la info respectiva.

Comment: Amigo, la api que utilizas no es oficial, tu podrias descargarte la base de datos, no pesa mucho el vinculo esta aqui:https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/ConsultaCP/Descarga.aspx , una rutina con Curl descargas 1 vez por semana, y no vas a depender de APIs de terceros

Comment: que tal, si has podido resolver el problema?? Recientemente mi equipo y yo estamos utilizando la misma API, pero en Jquery y se muestra un error, además de que el codigo que proporciona el sitio oficial tiene errores sintacticos.

Answer (score 0):

El API no es oficial de SEPOMEX, incluso el desarrollado "[Joel Rojas](https://whois.domaintools.com/hckdrk.mx)" Anuncio que te tienes que registrar para poder usarlo a partir del 1 de abril 2021.

> A partir del 1 de abril del 2021 de forma obligatoria se tendrá que mandar un token para poder seguir usando la API. Por ahora se puede seguir usando con normalidad, u opcionalmente se puede mandar el token. El sistema ya esta preparado para recibir el token desde este momento, por lo que ya se puede registrar y crear sus proyectos necesarios para obtener su token y realizar pruebas.

> Si tiene dudas, creamos una sección de Capacitación, donde podrás encontrar una serie de video tutoriales para enseñar el funcionamiento del nuevo sistema.

Su API [esta bien hecho y bien documentado](https://api-sepomex.hckdrk.mx/documentacion/docs), pero al ser un servicio de tercero  te puedes esperar que en algun momento se vuelva de costo o deje de estar en operacion.

Te recomiendo que descargues la Base de datos y generas el API en tu aplicacion

https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/ConsultaCP/CodigoPostal_Exportar.aspx